# Codename One screen shrinkage

Tags: codenameone

I have a form with two texfields. Once one of the textfields get focus and the virtual keyboard is launched, the form/screen is shrinked and the controls are pushed up. Is there a way to counter this?

Answer (score 1):

When you have text fields inside a container one of the parents must be scrollable.

At this time Android shrinks the screen to make room for the virtual keyboard but if the screen is scrollable this shouldn't be an issue. Notice that on iOS the screen isn't shrunk but scrollability is increased to leave room for the keyboard so you need that anyway.